# Production Deployment of CustomLabel using VS Code (INVALID_ID_FIELD: Source validate did not run tests in the org)

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, vs-code, customlabel, production

I am trying to deploy customLabels to the production org. But, I am not able to deploy it as it asks to run the test classes. As we know the custom label is just the configurations, not the codes. So, we don't need to run the test classes. My production org is a very new org and it doesn't have any class or test class till now.

**Please help me to fix this problem. Thanks in Advance!!!**

My package.xml contains the following value only.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">

    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomLabel</name>
    </types>

    <version>47.0</version>
</Package>
```

I am using the following command to deploy it.

**sfdx force:source:deploy --checkonly -x ./manifest/package.xml -u myProdUserName --testlevel RunLocalTests**

When I run this command, it successfully validates the deployment and generates the **JobId**. When I run the next command to deploy it gives an error - "**INVALID_ID_FIELD: Source validate did not run tests in the org**".

**sfdx force:source:deploy --targetusername myProdUserName --validateddeployrequestid JobId**

For all these operations, I am referring to this link of the salesforce.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_build_mdapi_production.htm

I took some help from this link as well. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply Kris!

I have removed the testevel and run this command. But it doesn't work in that case. See the screenshot.
[image: Error of production deployment using SFDX]

I found one way to deploy the custom labels by using the following command. 
(Removed --checkonly)

**sfdx force:source:deploy -x ./manifest/package.xml -u myProdUserName --testlevel RunLocalTests**

It has only one problem that it directly deploys the components (custom labels). It means, we didn't get the option to keep this deployment as a future-ready(Quick deploy) which we do in the changeset.

I will update here for the knowledge if I find something or Please tell me if you get it.

Comment: @Ghansham Kumar.
I have tried deploying with testLevel as runLocaltests but it says "INVALID_ID_FIELD: Source validate did not succeed."
I am trying to have a validate only option for metadata deployment of salesforce.
The ID from deploy call is being passed to deployRecentValidation call from which we should get a validation ID, but calling deployRecentValidation getting error as above.
What should i do? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You're specifying `--checkonly` in your command. This means it's just validating and it won't deploy(screenshot from your documentation link). You may want to keep this if you're testing the validation portion.

[image]

2. testLevel is an optional field and you can just ignore it if you want the default behavior in production to take affect
   [image]

You should be able to do the following to validate

```
sfdx force:source:deploy --checkonly -x ./manifest/package.xml -u myProdUserName
```

And then the following to deploy

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -x ./manifest/package.xml -u myProdUserName
```

Also, you can always do the following to get help in the CLI

```
sfdx force:source:deploy --help
```